# Proving a uniform bound on a sequence of elements in $\ell_1^+$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, inequality

Let $A\subset\ell_1^+$ and let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \in C(X)^+:=\{f\in C(X): f(x)\geq 0\,\, , \forall x\in X\}$, where X is a compact metric space. Suppose the following hold:
\begin{gathered}
1. \sup_{x\in X} |f_n(x)|\leq M_1.\\
2. \sup_{w\in A, x\in X}|\sum_{n=1}^\infty w_nf_n(x)|\leq M_2.\\
\end{gathered}

Prove that there exists $M_3 $ such that $\sup_{w\in A}|\sum_{n=1}^\infty w_n|\leq M_3$.

---

I think this should be true primarily because I can't think of a counter example. The uniform bound on $\sum_{n=1}^\infty w_n^kf_n(x)$ as well as the non-negativity are strong conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that implicitly $k$ is a positive integer. We only need to prove that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the number $w_n$ is less than $1$, since we have then $$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} w_n^k \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} w_n$$ and the sequence $(w_n)$ is summable by assumption.

Let us assume that $w_{n_0} > 1$ for some integer $n_0$, and choose $x \in X$. I guess that $\mathcal{C}(X)^+$ denotes the set of continuous functions on $X$ taking strictly positive values (the result is clearly false if we only assume non-negative). Then $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n(x) w_n^k \geq f_{n_0}(x) w_{n_0}^k$$ tends to $+ \infty$ when $k$ tends to $+ \infty$, which contradicts our assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm sorry my notation was confusing before. $w_n^k$ does not denote exponentiation but rather the n-th term in the k-th sequence. I've edited the question.

Comment: But then, it seems to be false: first you clearly need to make some assumption on the $f_n$'s in order to prevent the case $f_n = 0$. But, even if you assume $f_n > 0$ for instance, you can just take $f_n = e^{-n}$ (a constant function), and $A$ the sets of sequence of the form $e^{n} \delta_n$ (the only non-zero term is the $n$th term and its value is $e^n$). Then the $f_n$'s are uniformly bounded by $1$ so that 1 holds. And the sum in 2 is always equal to $1$ so that 2 holds too. But there is clearly no uniform bound on the $\ell^1$ norm of the elements of $A$.